# why do I have to use cin.ignore when I not using getline()?

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    while(true)
    {
      cout << "\nEnter an integer: ";
      cin >> i;
      if( cin.good() ) 
      {

        break; 
      }
      cin.clear();
      cout << "Incorrect input";
    }
    cout << "integer is "<< i;

    return 0;
}
```

However when I executed the code it kept infinitely printing `Enter a number: Incorrect Input`
after I entered the first input which was `nine` or anything that was not an integer.
I tried a lot of things and finally ended up with a code but I can't understand why do I have yo use `cin.ignore()` when I am not using `getline()`. The code I ended up with:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter an integer: ";
        cin >> i;
        if( cin.good() ) 
        {
            break; 
        }
        cin.clear();
        cout << "Incorrect input";
        cin.ignore(10,'\n');    //Why this line if I am not using getline?
    }
    cout << "integer is "<< i;

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I knew we had to use `cin.ignore()` before using `getline()` cause unlike cin>> it does'nt ignore the '\n' character. However nowhere in the code have I used getline() so why the error. Can you please explain...

Comment: If the input did not succeed then whatever prevented it is still in the buffer. As an example, if you entered `a` then the next time around you'd try and fail to read that `a` again.

Comment: On a side note, `cin >> i; if( cin.good() ) { ... }` should be `if (cin >> i) { ... }`.  And use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` instead of `cin.ignore(10,'\n')`.

Comment: Stuff that's left over in your input buffer causes a problem if the next extraction doesn't ignore it.  You are correct that `getline()` does not ignore `\n`.  Do you think that `cin >> i;` will ignore non-numeric input left in the input buffer from the last loop iteration?

Comment: Don't use `ignore` before `getline` to discard unwanted characters. That approach leads to accidentally discarding characters you wanted to read because some path to the `getline` did not leave unwanted characters in the stream. Instead  only `ignore` stuff when you're absolutely certain you want to `ignore` it. The best place for `ignore` is after the transaction that left unwanted characters in the stream. This is what the code sample is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the `ignore()` reads the rest of the line and drops it. You want to do this because otherwise you would simply try to re-read the same value again and again and always fail.

Example:

```
 Enter an integer:
 Fify Six                  <-- If I typed that.
```

Then the line:

```
 cin >> i;                 // This will fail (as i is an int)
                           // and there is no integer value on the input.
```

So you fail to read the value. Note: this does not remove the input it is still waiting to be read. So if you simply clear the state and try again you will fail again as you are trying to read the same value repeatedly (always failing).

Now you could remove a single character and throw it away and try again. That would be a valid technique to try and eventually resolve this. And it would get there after 7 attempts (each attempt throwing away a character).

But usually you just throw away the whole line. This is because the `std::cin` is buffered and only passed to the application a line at a time. i.e. You type some text and then hit enter and the buffer is flushed to your code at that point for parsing. If the user had done something wrong, usually the whole line is wrong so discarding it just gets to the next set of user input.

You should note that this buffered input model is tied with the `std::cout` stream as well. It makes sure that when you attempt to read from the `std::cin` the output stream is flushed automatically so the question you are answering on the input matches what is being asked on the output. This leads to 1 question and 1 answer per line from the user. So incorrect input can simply be dropped a line at a time.

Now this does not stop the user from abusing the system and typing multiple answers onto one line. Which then are all ignored at the same time when an answer is wrong.